# Compressing Images as JPEG from $_FILES array

Tags: php, image, image-uploading

I've been searching the web and trying to understand how to scale and compress my image uploads with PHP. I want users to be able to upload, say, a 1MB file, but then to actually save a much more compressed version of that file to my server since for this application, details aren't as important. I've come up with the following code:

```
print_r($_FILES);

// Check if the file size is too big
if ($_FILES['image']['size'] > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
{
    // Compress it 
    imagejpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 60);

    print_r($_FILES);

    // Check file size again
    if ($_FILES['image']['size'] > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        // Image too big still...
        return;
    }
}
```

At this point, I'm every time getting caught in my "// Check again" block and in both my "print_r" statements, I'm seeing the file size remain the same. Can anyone please point me in the right direction in terms of what I'm doing wrong? Is there an entirely different but better way of handling this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [compress image file size on upload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254083/compress-image-file-size-on-upload)

Answer (score 1):

Your [`imagejpeg`](http://www.php.net/imagejpeg) function isn't being passed the correct arguments. You need to first open the file using a GD function like [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) and use the resource it returns to manipulate the image (in this case, compress it).

Try something like:

```
// Create image resource from file (try a different function if not JPG)
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

// Check if successfully opened
if($im){
    // Resize the resource and save it back to the temporary file name
    imagejpeg($im, $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 60);
}
```

Comment: Hm, that makes sense, though I'm still seeing the exact same behavior when editing my code in the above way. My $_FILES array still shows an image that's the same size that I started with. Could the compression be not working as expected somehow?

Comment: Are you on shared Web hosting? You might not have permissions to write back to the same path. You might have to save it elsewhere. Check your file permissions, and make sure you're writing to somewhere you have permissions to write new files.