# How to compress an image without resizing it in code igniter

Tags: image, codeigniter

IF I have upload an image of 1mb its too big for our server and takne more time to retreive.

so Now i want to compress this image without re sizing or without affecting quality.

Thanks in advance

Comment: CodeIgniter doesn't have this [feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254083/compress-image-file-size-on-upload), you have to [do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696187/php-how-to-compress-images-without-losing-visible-quality-automatically) on your own:

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an external library for images management, GD or ImageMagick will be fine.